# Where can I find a semantic or syntactic analysis of a Swedish verb?

Tags: syntax, semantics, reference-request, swedish

Are there any books which will talk about the specific semantic or syntactic properties of a specific word (in my case, a verb in the Swedish language).

I know there are many general reference books on syntax and semantics, but I am envisioning a reference work that talks about the function of a word in the context of modern semantic and syntactic theory, for example, spelling out precisely the proper usage of the verb, how it inflects and why so, etc., far beyond what a standard dictionary or table of verb conjugations might do. As I am an amateur I am lacking specific terms to express what I am searching for.

Comment: "verb" or "word"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To long for a comment ...

Which Swedish verb do you mean? What languages do you read comfortably? When you are lucky, there is a paper (published in a journal or in conference proceedings) on that specific word. The draw-back is that this paper is probably completely unreadable for a lay person, because it uses terminology defined in other works (to be consulted) and is written in a very dense style..

When you even luckier, the word was deemed important enough to be treated in a **grammar** of the Swedish language. (Don't think of schoolbook grammar with conjugation tables, think of a work ten times as thick.) In this case, you may even have the chance to understand something of it.

However, for most of the words of the Swedish language, such kind of in-depth analysis will be not available at all.